# Initialization of RMSPropOptimizer

Tags: tensorflow

In TensorFlow (Python), when adding to the graph a `tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer`, are any additional variables added that need initialization? If yes, how can I get access to them and initialize them manually? (I'd rather not use `tf.global_variables_initializer`). In other words:
(1) How can I decide which initializer to use?
(2) How can I add the initilizer op to the graph, specifically for these variables?

EDIT 1:

I'm referring here to any new `tf.Variable` that is added to the graph whenever I add the `RMSPropOptimizer`, and how it is initialized (just like other `tf.Variable`s). I'm not referring to the arguments in constructor of the `RMSPropOptimizer`, (which are hyper parameters of the model).

Answer (score 0):

> In TensorFlow (Python), when adding to the graph a tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer, are any additional variables added that need initialization?

Yes.

> If yes, how can I get access to them and initialize them manually? (I'd rather not use tf.global_variables_initializer).

From the docs:

> `tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer.__init__(learning_rate, decay=0.9, momentum=0.0, epsilon=1e-10, use_locking=False, centered=False, name='RMSProp')`

There are at least 3 (`decay`, `momentum`, and `epsilon`).

> In other words: (1) How can I decide which initializer to use?

This I don't have a good answer to - I've been told in class "just use Adam". That might be good advice in general, but I imagine there are cases where others work better. This might be worth searching online for blog posts or survey papers or something.

> (2) How can I add the initializer op to the graph, specifically for these variables?

You can pass them into the constructor as named parameters.

Comment: What I meant in my question is whether the RMSPropOptimizer adds to the graph new tf.variables that need to be initialized. I wasn't referring to the arguments in the constructor (which are hyper parameters for the network)

Comment: Yes, those variables will need to be initialized as well.